# graphing a function with pgfplots x-intercept is not showing

Tags: pgfplots

I have a function $f(x)=\sqrt{{1-2e^{-x^2}}}$ I wish to plot.

The problem I am encountering is that the function has a vertical tangent at $\sqrt{\ln{2}}$ which is also an x-intercept.
The graph stops short of intersecting the x-axis.

Here is my effort thus far.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-2.5,xmax=2.5,ymin=-1.5,ymax=1.5,
  xlabel=$x$,   
  ylabel=$y$,
  xtick=\empty,
  ytick=\empty,
  xticklabels={,,},
  yticklabels={,,},
  x label style={yshift=-6ex,xshift=2ex},
  y label style={yshift=1ex,xshift=-5ex},
 axis lines=middle,
 axis line style={->}
  ]

\addplot[ultra thick,smooth,blue,samples=400,domain={(ln(2))^0.5:2}] {(1-2*e^(-x^2))^0.5};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:
[image]

Comment: Unrelated: When using PGFPlots, you should always set compat level - see my answer

Comment: You are not really using PGFPlots for anything - you overwrite the style, that could make your graphs consistent and you do not use ticks, scale or legend. Consider just using TikZ. As you do not show any scale, you might want the `axis equal` option to at least show the "correct" shape of your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select this one point and make it zero like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-2.5, xmax=2.5, 
ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5,
xlabel=$x$,   
ylabel=$y$,
ticks=none,
x label style={yshift=-6ex, xshift=2ex},
y label style={yshift=1ex, xshift=-5ex},
axis lines=middle,
axis line style={->}
]
\addplot[
ultra thick, smooth, blue, 
samples=50,
domain=(ln(2))^0.5:2,
y filter/.expression={x==(ln(2))^0.5?0:y},
] {(1-2*e^(-x^2))^0.5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Grap with blue curve touching x-axis]

Comment: Thanks. I know about axis equal, and nearly always use it. My concern is that the graph is not continuing to meet the X axis.